# How to use document.getElementById() with styled components in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to use JS functions like `document.getElementById()` in my **react** project. I am new to styled components and don't know how to use these functions with them.
Do not refer to the official 'styled-components' page, I have already seen it.

Comment: does the element have an ID? if so, you can use it

Comment: I know about id argument but where exactly should I put this statement?
That is whether inside react function return ( ) or outside?

Comment: after the element is created?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `useRef` react Hook for this.

```
const reqElement = React.useRef(null);
```

Now, you can add `ref={reqElement}` in your required element.

After that you can use `reqElement.current` to do those things that you can do via `document.getElementById()` in javaScript.

[useRef hook refrence](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: It was really helpful comment and I have finally solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is the right way when you want to keep reference to an element in React

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found an answer to my question here. I laying down the gathered information in the following points.

1. Styled Components does have an id parameter but we *must not* use it in react for DOM functionalities as the main motive behind react is to prevent frequent changes in the real DOM.
2. We can use **useRef()** hook in React functional components for passing references in react. (Look at Dibas's answer above.)
3. I was making a mistake of not using **useState()** hook to store the state of the component, instead I used an identifier, which is wrong as **useState** helps to re render the component whenever the state changes.
4. Use a cleaning function in **useEffect()** hook to prevent memory leak.

Here is a link to a Parallax effect video https://youtu.be/Q5y6pwoE3cM hope this can help you.